# Git diff without checkout branch

Tags: git

As an example:

In the kernel source code, it has a lot of tags. I can diff them, such as:

git diff v2.6.37-rc3 v2.6.38-rc4

and I get the right output.

Now I copy `.git` directory to another place, and in this new .git directory, I can also use

```
git diff v2.6.37-rc3 v2.6.38-rc4
```

to get the right output.

But, I have another branch such as "mydev". I can't checkout to this mydev branch, and do the `git diff v2.6.37-rc3 v2.6.38-rc4` commmand.

How can I do it?

Comment: When you say you can't checkout the branch or do the `git diff`, what commands are you trying and what errors do you get?

Answer (score 1):

You can' t just copy the .git directory of a non-bare GIT repository and expect to be able to checkout branches.  When non-bare, the repository has an index and needs a corresponding working directory.   Note that some GIT commands and arguments (like 'diff' with two commits) operate only on the repository objects/commits and thus don't need a working directory - hence they work, as you've seen.  But other commands (like 'diff' between on commit and the working directory) need the working directory.

Answer (score 0):

You should get the same output as before. Having a branch in the repository should not matter.